# Counting Unique values across 2 columns based on a condition for a 3rd column

Tags: excel-365

I have been searching forums all day and found many solutions, using Unique, Filter, Sumproduct, Countif but none that can resolve my issue. They all provide a unique count of the 2 columns, i.e. A1:A2, B1:B2, rather than A1, A2, B1, B2.

Example Data as follows

[image: Table Example]

I want to count Unique values in first 2 columns where 3rd equals "Ignore". This should be 5 as combination of a,b,c,d and e all used. However any counts i get come out at 8. I can get counts working for columns A and B in isolation using C as condition, but when treat 2 columns as one range it doesn't work as desired. This i can see is due to joining data in rows rather than appending into one bigger column.
I started with
=UNIQUE(FILTER(K2:L23,M2:M23="Ignore",""),TRUE,FALSE)
This shows the 2 column values for "Ignore" rows, i can see only values a-e used across both columns.
Next i tried
=COUNT(LEN(UNIQUE(FILTER(K2:K23,M2:M23="Ignore","")&FILTER(L2:L23,M2:M23="Ignore",""),FALSE,FALSE)))
When i Evaluate formula, i can see it assesses 2 columns separate and rather than appending it is joining, screens below to illustrate. Any help or suggestions warmly appreciated.
[image: First Filter identifies unique values in first column]

[image: Second Filter identifies unique values in Second column]

[image: Now joins values rather than keeping separate]

Note examples from Evaluate formula do hold slight different values, this is just from me testing each solution to see how impacts counts.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest and easiest way will be a helper column. A plain `CONCAT(A1, B1)` will be sufficient. This way, you will create an extra column of unique strings, and your initial method will work.

If you want to create a one-fits-all solution completely nested inside a formula, recreate this helper column using `MAP(str_a_array, str_b_array, LAMBDA(a, b, CONCAT(a, b)))`. But I probably won't bother as the first method is more obvious to work with.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to reply. I am not sure of your logic in using concat as can see formula currently carries out that logic which is undesired. Do you mean to use the concat as a "pre step" to use values to remove duplicates?

Comment: @Danny So far, I assume based on your description that you want to filter all unique combos of strings in A and B (if these are the column labels). If you seek to get something else done, it will help if you add to your question an illustration of a desired outcome. I may be able to help you better then.

Comment: Thanks but I got it to work and shared solution in this post.

Answer (score 0):

> =IFERROR(ROWS(UNIQUE(TOCOL(FILTER(B:C,EV:EV="Ignore","")))), 0)

The use of `TOCOL` was used to append column data. Various checks carried out amending test data proved count of unique values correct each time.

A more detailed description:

- `FILTER(B:C, EV:EV="Ignore","")` - Filters the range B:C, selecting rows where the corresponding cell in column EV equals "Ignore". If "Ignore" is not found, it returns an empty string.
- `UNIQUE(TOCOL(...))` - Converts the filtered range into a single column and then returns the unique values from this column.
- `ROWS(...)` - Counts the number of rows in the unique values obtained.
- `IFERROR(..., 0)`: If any part of the formula results in an error (like a reference error), it returns 0 instead of displaying the error.

In summary, the formula counts the number of unique rows in the range `B:C` where column `EV` equals "Ignore", returning 0 in case of an error.